# changing frames based on radio button answer

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying a simple experiment, I have 3 frames, frame 1 has two labels - "for page 2" and "for page 3", it also has 2 radio buttons corresponding to the labels. based on which radio button is selected, when the user hits the next page button, I want the button to bring the user to the selected page

this is the code -

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the main container that holds all the frames
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)


        self.frames = {}

        # adding frames to the dictionary
        for F in (Page1,Page2,Page3):

             frame = F(container,self)

             self.frames[F] = frame

             frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

        self.show_frame(Page1)

    def show_frame(self,page_name):

        #SHOWS A FRAME WITH THE GIVEN NAME
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.grid()

    #STACKING THE FRAMES
    #frame = self.frames[cont]
    #frame.tkraise()

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        lbl1 = tk.Label(self,text = "for page 2",font =("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl1.grid(row=1,sticky="W")

        lbl2 = tk.Label(self,text = "for page 3",font =("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W")

        btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="next page", font=('MS', 24, 'bold'))
        btn1.grid(row=3,column = 0,columnspan=1)
        #btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)


        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar()

        rButton1 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=True)
        rButton1.grid(row=2,sticky = "W")

        rButton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=False)
        rButton2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky = "W")

        if self.var1.get() == 1:
            btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3)

        if self.var1.get() == 0:
            btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)


class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        lbl = tk.Label(self,text="This is page 2",font=("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl.pack()


class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        lbl = tk.Label(self,text="This is page 3",font=("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl.pack()

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I assumed that by using a few basic conditions (located in my PageOne class) -

```
        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar()

    rButton1 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=True)
    rButton1.grid(row=2,sticky = "W")

    rButton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=False)
    rButton2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky = "W")

    if self.var1.get() == 1:
        btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3)

    if self.var1.get() == 0:
        btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)
```

I would be able to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to work. The conditions in my if statements are integers but to my knowledge 1 represents True and 0; False anyway? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. I didn't handle making sure the radiobutton isn't selected by default. I left that as an exercise to you. Although, if you're wanting to just switch pages like this I'd just use buttons (`tk/ttk.Button`), then you don't have to worry about handling the radiobutton. Although, that's just my preference either will work fine of course. You can just bind each button to switch the page. I commented the buttons out in your modified code below.
If you're wanting to create buttons / radiobuttons to have a forward / back option for each page. You can just iterate over the controllers frames to see which is the current, and create two buttons similar to the ones below to move to the other frames.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the main container that holds all the frames
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)


        self.frames = {}

        # adding frames to the dictionary
        for F in (Page1,Page2,Page3):

             frame = F(container,self)

             self.frames[F] = frame

             frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

        self.show_frame(Page1)

    def show_frame(self,page_name):

        #SHOWS A FRAME WITH THE GIVEN NAME
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.grid()

    #STACKING THE FRAMES
    #frame = self.frames[cont]
    #frame.tkraise()

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        lbl1 = tk.Label(self,text = "for page 2",font =("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl1.grid(row=1,sticky="W")

        lbl2 = tk.Label(self,text = "for page 3",font =("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W")

        btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="next page", font=('MS', 24, 'bold'))
        btn1.grid(row=3,column = 0,columnspan=1)
        #btn1['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)


        self.var1 = tk.BooleanVar()

        #rButton1 = tk.Button(self, text='Show Page 2', command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Page2))
        #rButton1.grid(row=2, sticky="W")
        #rButton2 = tk.Button(self, text='Show Page 3', command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Page3))
        #rButton2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")

        rButton1 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=True,
            command=self.switch_pages)
        rButton1.grid(row=2,sticky = "W")

        rButton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self,variable = self.var1,value=False,
            command=self.switch_pages)
        rButton2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky = "W")

    def switch_pages(self):

        if not self.var1.get():
            self.controller.show_frame(Page3)
        else:
            self.controller.show_frame(Page2)


class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        lbl = tk.Label(self,text="This is page 2",font=("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl.pack()


class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        lbl = tk.Label(self,text="This is page 3",font=("Helvetica",12,"bold"))
        lbl.pack()

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work, gives me this -     if not self.var1.get():
AttributeError: Page1 instance has no attribute 'controller'

Comment: sounds like you didn't set `self.controller = controller`. Try copying / pasting above code if you didn't already?

Comment: ideally, I would still like to have the "Next Page" button retain its functionality. I've done it this way because I intend on using it in a larger project, something like this: a questionnaire with 10 questions, each with a corresponding "Yes" and "No" radio button. Upon having completed the questionnaire, once they hit the "Next page" button I want a particular frame displayed, the frame in question will be populated with text, as an example the text could read, "Based on your choices, this is your recommendation..."

Comment: cheers, thanks it worked! but ideally i would like it to do as my newer comment mentioned